# DataGridView with horizontal columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to have a horizontal columns in DataGridView, with ability to bind those columns?

Comment: Not very satisfactorily, it seems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853663/is-it-possible-to-switch-rows-and-columns-in-a-datagridview

Comment: That solution doesn't suit me. I was wondering about some kind of solution that will support binding. It seems that there are no easy ones=(

Comment: you need to just pivot the query which is fetching the results. Pivot is a keyword which will convert columns into rows and vice-versa.

Comment: @MARKAND Bhatt by query do you mean SQL query or LINQ?

Comment: In sql server. Take a look at this link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to Flip the DataGridView instead **Flip the DataSet to bind**

Try this:

```
public DataSet FlipDataSet(DataSet my_DataSet)
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 foreach (DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
 {
   DataTable table = new DataTable();

   for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {   table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));  }

   DataRow r;
   for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
   { 
     r = table.NewRow();
     r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
     for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
     {  r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k]; }
     table.Rows.Add(r);
   }
   ds.Tables.Add(table);
 }

 return ds;
}
```

For more details visit [Displaying-Vertical-Rows-in-DataGrid-View](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19313/Displaying-Vertical-Rows-in-DataGrid-View)

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for, since it doesn't support binding.