# list data base column cells horizontally on adata gridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

i have table that has three columns and i want to show this table on data grid view , but i want to show column 2 say its name " 2nd_column " cells horizontally on the data grid mean the data grid column will be like that" 1st_column , 2nd_column_first-cell , 2nd_column_second-cell , 3rd_column " that what i want to do hope to help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you asked this question earlier today already but anyways

**OPTION 1**

you could PIVOT your result set then use that as your datasource. The link below will show you how to use the PIVOT command in SQL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx

**OPTION 2**

Otherwise you could do it manually like the answer suggested in the link below:

[DataGridView with horizontal columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580147/datagridview-with-horizontal-columns)

The result will be your list of schools displayed horizontally rather than vertically. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi Ben ,i want to do this in a windows application form could you show me how

Comment: Oh ok in that case option 1 still applies. I've edited option 2. @mostafa