# How to display the specific values of a column in GridView Horizontally?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I cannot explain further in the title so ill explain it here more.

This is my current interface in my gridview:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Section   |   Exam   |   Normal Values   |   Result    |   Result Date   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
           | Calcium  |    NormalValue1   |   Result1   |    1-1-2014     |
Chemistry  |--------------------------------------------------------------|
           |  Sodium  |    NormalValue2   |   Result2   |    1-2-2014     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Section   |   Exam   |   Normal Values   |   1-1-2014   |    1-2-2014    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
           | Calcium  |   NormalValue1    |    Result1   |                |
Chemistry  |--------------------------------------------------------------|
           | Sodium   |   NormalValue2    |              |     Result2    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Here's a print screen for better view: http://prntscr.com/4re3on

I need to display the Dates horizontally with the results below them. I get the data via stored procedure. I tried rotating the GridView into columns but it does not look right. How can i do this?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim o_Dataset As New DataSet()

    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(DataSource.ConnectionString)
        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
            Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Station.dbo.[sp_Nurse_GetPatient_LabResult_NormalValues_Tabular_New]"
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            'sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@labsectionid", "H"))
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@HospNum", Session.Item("HospNum")))
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            sqlReader.Close()
            sqlAdapter.Fill(o_Dataset)
            grdReports_H.DataSource = o_Dataset.Tables(0)
            grdReports_H.DataBind()
            GroupGridView(grdReports_H.Rows, 0, 3)
            sqlConn.Close()

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

This code just hides my unwanted data

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound_H(sender As Object, a As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If a.Row.Cells(0).Text = "A" Then
        a.Row.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This code just groups my Data, like the one displayed under section (Chemistry):

```
Private Sub GroupGridView(gvrc As GridViewRowCollection, startIndex As Integer, total As Integer)
    If total = 0 Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim i As Integer, count As Integer = 1
    Dim lst As New ArrayList()
    lst.Add(gvrc(0))
    Dim ctrl = gvrc(0).Cells(startIndex)
    For i = 1 To gvrc.Count - 1
        Dim nextCell As TableCell = gvrc(i).Cells(startIndex)
        If ctrl.Text = nextCell.Text Then
            count += 1
            nextCell.Visible = False
            lst.Add(gvrc(i))
        Else
            If count > 1 Then
                ctrl.RowSpan = count
                GroupGridView(New GridViewRowCollection(lst), startIndex + 1, total - 1)
            End If
            count = 1
            lst.Clear()
            ctrl = gvrc(i).Cells(startIndex)
            lst.Add(gvrc(i))
        End If
    Next
    If count > 1 Then
        ctrl.RowSpan = count
        GroupGridView(New GridViewRowCollection(lst), startIndex + 1, total - 1)
    End If
    count = 1
    lst.Clear()
End Sub
```

This is my aspx file:

```
    <style type="text/css">
  .hiddencol
  {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

   <asp:GridView  OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound_H" ID="grdReports_H" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"   CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" style="text-align: center">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle  BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
       <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField  DataField="labsectionid" HeaderText="SectionID_H" ItemStyle-Width ="200px" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Section"  ItemStyle-Height="10px"  HeaderText="Section" ItemStyle-Width="40px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Exam" HeaderText="Exam" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="NormalValue" HeaderText="Normal Values" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="ResultDate" HeaderText="Result Date" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
       </Columns>
```

Comment: I think it would be easiest to manipulate the data in the DataTable rather than mess with the GridView.

Comment: Rather than having bound fields make use of Templatefield and have HTML table with the format you like inside that field. Make use of `<%# Eval("Column")%>` to display your data in this table.

Comment: I agree with Sam. Use a TemplateField in the ASPX.

Comment: thank you for the replies. I'll try TemplateField. Do you have any samples/links that would help best in my situation?

Comment: @Dale This will help you out :) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46486/Pivoting-DataTable-Simplified

Comment: i think that is to advance @Thirisangu. And I am using vb code.

Comment: @Dale otherwise you can pivot the data table and bind to grid using LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answered my problem. By using proper for loops and conditions. 
Please refer to the link: [Print Datagrid table with many column headers accross multiple pages in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183316/print-datagrid-table-with-many-column-headers-accross-multiple-pages-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having bound fields make use of Templatefield and have HTML table with the format you like inside that field. Make use of `<%# Eval("Column")%>` to display your data in this table.

Here's an example `GridView`. (NOTE: This is just an example may not work as is. Just get the idea)

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTest">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Section</td>
                                <td>Exam</td>
                                <td>Normal Values</td>
                                <td>1-1-2014</td>
                                <td>1-2-2014</td>
                            </tr>                            
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# Eval("Column1") %></td>
                                <%--Add other columns from your DataSet/DataTable match the columns--%>
                            </tr>                      
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Read more here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

You could do the same with `Repeater`

**UPDATE 1**

How to dynamically change the header

Try this

Have a Literal control in your header (This control can spit out HTML during render)

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
       <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>                                                       
</HeaderTemplate>
```

In your code behind do something like this in `ItemCreated` event

```
  protected void gvTest_ItemCreated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Get the header row.
        GridViewRow headerRow = gvTest.HeaderRow;

        // Get the Literal control from the header row.
        Literal ltHeader = (Literal)headerRow.FindControl("Literal1");

        if (ltHeader != null)
        {
            // Build this headerRow string variable based on the values you want
            string headerRow = "<td>Section</td><td>Exam</td><td>Normal Values</td><td>1-1-2014</td><td>1-2-2014</td>";
            ltHeader.Text = headerRow;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How could I assign a dynamic data to the <HeaderTemplate> ? is that possible?

Comment: You can't do it from design view but it's possible if you dynamically create the GridView from code behind. But, that's bit of work for you. Use ItemCreated event if you do.

Comment: See my update to this answer. I didn't try this code but it should work.

Comment: Apologies for C# code. I'm a C# guy. But there are C# to VB.Net converters on-line if you don't know how to convert this code to VB.Net :-D

Comment: The dates 1-1-2014 and 1-2-2014 are coming from the database, it should not be hardcoded, i want to make it look like this sir. http://prntscr.com/4re3on

Comment: That's why I asked you to build the string variable headerRow from DB values

Comment: Show some sample data in o_Dataset.Tables(0) table

Comment: I converted C# to Vb.net and added the codes but nothing was displayed on the headers sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can achieve that using PIVOT in SQL Server. PIVOT essentially converts row values into columns. Have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query for quick introduction. By doing this way, you can get away with some of the UI code about transforming rows into columns. Transformed dataset will come straight from stored proc.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but unfortunately I should not edit/move the query because that stored procedure is used in several parts of the system, I should only revise only in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is give your grid to autocolumn true option, then make a dataset from back-end (c#) which transform your data as your grid datasource. Finally bind the grid to datasource.

Refer below code :- [Is it possible to switch rows and columns in a datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853663/is-it-possible-to-switch-rows-and-columns-in-a-datagridview)

```
DataTable oldTable = new DataTable();

...

DataTable newTable = new DataTable();

newTable.Columns.Add("Field Name");
for (int i = 0; i < oldTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    newTable.Columns.Add();

for (int i = 0; i < oldTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow newRow = newTable.NewRow();

    newRow[0] = oldTable.Columns[i].Caption;
    for (int j = 0; j < oldTable.Rows.Count; j++)
        newRow[j+1] = oldTable.Rows[j][i];
    newTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

dataGridView.DataSource = newTable;
```