# Print Datagrid table with many column headers accross multiple pages in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, datagrid

I cannot explain further on the title so kindly base on the links below.
I am using DataGrid (not GridView), in ASP.net using VB code.

This is my current display in my datagrid
[click here to view picture1](http://prntscr.com/5axad0)
, and i want to make it like this [clck here to view picture2](http://prntscr.com/5cckt5)

My purpose is to split my datagrid into multiple datagrid if i have multiple columns.
I need to split them so that I can print it Google Chrome nicely. Because the print preview in picture 1 using javascript's window.print is that it auto-fits my multicolumn in one dataGrid, thus, if i have, let's say, 20columns of data, the spacing of my columns will be small and it will not be readable to users. like this [click here to view picture3](http://prntscr.com/5axdt9)

if you have suggestions on how to print my datagrid in browser, ill be thankful, 
TIA.

```
<asp:DataGrid Visible ="true" OnItemDataBound="Item_Bound" ID="dgSheet" 
   runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="black"  BorderStyle="None" 
   BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" Width="100%" PageSize="5"
   CssClass="Narrow" ForeColor="Black">
 <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" />
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#2980b9" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#2980b9" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <ItemStyle Font-Size="12px" Width="200"  ForeColor="#333333" />
 <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12px" Width="200"  ForeColor="black" />
 <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

My partial code behind for displaying my data in datagrid:

```
   Dim o_Row As DataRow
    Dim o_AdmDates As New Collection()
    Dim s_LastAdmDate As String = ""
    Dim s_AdmDate As String = ""
    Dim o_DerivedTable As New DataTable()

    With o_DerivedTable

        .Columns.Add("TransDate")
        .Columns.Add("Medication")
        .Columns.Add("Dosage")
        .Columns.Add("TransNum")
        .Columns.Add("AdministeredDate")
        .Columns.Add("newAdmed")
    End With

    'Sort by administered dates
    Dim o_FoundRows As DataRow() = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Select("", "AdministeredDate Desc")

    'Extract distinct  administered dates
    For Each o_Row In o_FoundRows
        s_AdmDate = Format(CDate(o_Row.Item("AdministeredDate")), KC_Date_Format2)

        If s_LastAdmDate <> s_AdmDate Then
            s_LastAdmDate = s_AdmDate
            o_AdmDates.Add(s_LastAdmDate)
        End If
    Next

    'Add administred date to derived table
    Dim o_Item As String
    For Each o_Item In o_AdmDates
        o_DerivedTable.Columns.Add(o_Item)
    Next


    'Loop through the administred date
    Dim o_NewRow As DataRow
    Dim o_NextRow As DataRow
    Dim i_Ctr As Integer
    Dim x_isNewRow As Boolean = True
    Dim i_MaxRec As Integer

    i_MaxRec = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

    For i_Ctr = 0 To i_MaxRec
        o_Row = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i_Ctr)
        If i_Ctr <> i_MaxRec Then
            o_NextRow = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i_Ctr + 1)
        End If

        If x_isNewRow Then
            o_NewRow = o_DerivedTable.NewRow()
        End If

        o_NewRow("TransDate") = o_Row("TransDate")
        o_NewRow("Medication") = o_Row("Medication")
        o_NewRow("Dosage") = o_Row("Dosage")
        o_NewRow("TransNum") = o_Row("TransNum")
        o_NewRow("AdministeredDate") = Format(CDate(o_Row("AdministeredDate")), KC_Date_Format2)
        o_NewRow("newAdmed") = o_Row("newAdmed")


        'Fill approriate result date column based on query
        For Each o_Item In o_AdmDates
            s_AdmDate = Format(CDate(o_Row("AdministeredDate")), KC_Date_Format2)
            Dim AdmTim As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(o_Row("AdministeredDate"))
            If s_AdmDate = o_Item Then
                o_NewRow(s_AdmDate) = AdmTim.ToString("hh:mm tt") + " - " + o_Row("UserID")
            End If
        Next

        If i_Ctr < i_MaxRec _
            AndAlso Not o_NextRow Is Nothing _
            AndAlso o_Row("TransDate") = o_NextRow("TransDate") _
            AndAlso o_Row("Medication") = o_NextRow("Medication") _
            AndAlso o_Row("AdministeredDate") = o_NextRow("AdministeredDate") Then
            x_isNewRow = False
        Else
            o_DerivedTable.Rows.Add(o_NewRow)
            x_isNewRow = True
        End If

    Next
    dgSheetPrint.DataSource = o_DerivedTable
    dgSheetPrint.DataBind()
```

Comment: You wont be able to do from serverside, provide generated code for the table.

Comment: @Ratna i've edited my question, you can look at my code behind.

Comment: I needed the html not the server side code, find my answer with my own table code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to say that you are not printing datagrid but the html generated by that.
Hence you need to do some thing on the client side. Since you have written you need to break the table and then print i am attaching an html page from where you can copy the code and change it to work with your html generated by the datagrid, you will need to atleast change the id of datagrid.

Code follows here

[since you didn't provided generated html i have made a similar table]

```
<table id="previousOrderExports" class="chromeTheme">
    <tr>
        <td class="bold">Export ID</td>
        <td class="bold">Request Type</td>
        <td class="bold">Timeframe</td>
        <td class="bold">Search Filter</td>
        <td class="bold">Search Term</td>
        <td class="bold">Requested on</td>
        <td class="bold">Processed on</td>
        <td class="bold">Export Status</td>
        <td class="bold">Download</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>143306</td>
        <td>manual</td>
        <td>11/8/14 - 12/8/14</td>
        <td>Timespan</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>12/08/14 03:37:00 AM PST</td>
        <td>12/08/14 03:37:08 AM PST</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td><a href="fghhsd.dsfd/sfre/143306">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>142873</td>
        <td>auto</td>
        <td>12/7/14 - 12/8/14</td>
        <td>Timespan</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>12/08/14 01:01:10 AM PST</td>
        <td>12/08/14 01:03:00 AM PST</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td><a href="fghhsd.dsfd/sfre/142873">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>142766</td>
        <td>auto</td>
        <td>12/7/14 - 12/8/14</td>
        <td>Timespan</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>12/07/14 11:01:03 PM PST</td>
        <td>12/07/14 11:02:04 PM PST</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td><a href="fghhsd.dsfd/sfre/142766">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>142752</td>
        <td>auto</td>
        <td>12/7/14 - 12/8/14</td>
        <td>Timespan</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>12/07/14 10:01:03 PM PST</td>
        <td>12/07/14 10:02:05 PM PST</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td><a href="fghhsd.dsfd/sfre/142752">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>142738</td>
        <td>auto</td>
        <td>12/7/14 - 12/8/14</td>
        <td>Timespan</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>12/07/14 09:01:03 PM PST</td>
        <td>12/07/14 09:02:07 PM PST</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td><a href="fghhsd.dsfd/sfre/142738">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>142723</td>
        <td>auto</td>
        <td>12/7/14 - 12/8/14</td>
        <td>Timespan</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>12/07/14 08:01:02 PM PST</td>
        <td>12/07/14 08:02:04 PM PST</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td><a href="fghhsd.dsfd/sfre/142723">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>142709</td>
        <td>auto</td>
        <td>12/7/14 - 12/8/14</td>
        <td>Timespan</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>12/07/14 07:01:03 PM PST</td>
        <td>12/07/14 07:02:04 PM PST</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td><a href="fghhsd.dsfd/sfre/142709">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Print" onclick="print_breakup_table()" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function print_breakup_table()
    {
        var tableid = "previousOrderExports"; //id of table in this case cliend side id of your datagrid
        var fixedcols = 2;// no. of columns 0 index based that will be repeated on every page
        var eachpagecols = 3; // no. of columns that will get printed on each page
        var colCount = 0;
        $('#' + tableid + ' tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
                colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
            } else {
                colCount++;
            }
        });
        colCount--; //get 0 based columncount
        var col_left_after_fixed_col = colCount - fixedcols;
        var pagerequired = col_left_after_fixed_col / eachpagecols;
        if ((col_left_after_fixed_col % eachpagecols)>0) {
            pagerequired++;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < pagerequired; i++) {
            var html = "<table>";
            var startcols = fixedcols + (i * eachpagecols);
            var endcols = startcols + eachpagecols;
            //add fixed cols
            $('#' + tableid + ' tr').each(function () {
                html += "<tr>";
                $(this).children('td').each(function (index, object) {
                    if (index <= fixedcols) {
                        html += "<td>" + $(this).html() + "</td>";
                    } else {
                        if (index <= endcols && index >= startcols) {
                            html += "<td>" + $(this).html() + "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                });
                html += "</tr>";
            });



            html += "</table>";
            myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600');
            myWindow.document.write(html);


            myWindow.document.close();


            myWindow.focus();
            myWindow.print();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: i have removed the table you created and changed the table id on the javascript into my DataGrid ID, it works but i need to tweak it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use window.print: do not rely on inline styles but create 2 separate style sheets: media="screen" & media="print"

Use a reporting engine to fully control the result, e.g. Crystal Report, Telerik Reporting etc

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 and im having problems regarding crystal reports, that is why i am using datagrid instead

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specifically program a view that have the tables the way you want. Then you can add a button to print it

```
 <a class="miniprint" href="/url/to/print/view">Print</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.miniprint', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    var url = self.attr("href");
    $("#printjob").remove();
    $('<iframe id="printjob" src="' + url + '">')
    .load(function () {
        this.focus();
        document.getElementById("printjob").contentWindow.print();
    })
    .css({ position: "absolute", left: "-10000px", top: "0px" })
    .appendTo(document.body);
});
```

Also, I suggest to tell Google Chrome to print it in landscape using

```
@media print {
  @page {size: landscape}
}
```

Comment: i already have the table that i want to be printed, which is the the DataGrid. My problem is on how will i split my datagrid into multiple columns, let's say 7 columns so that it will be sorted weekly.