# C# - DataGridView Format

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, formatting

Is there a way to get the output (from the code below) to print as a single row spanning across multiple columns in a datagridview? I would like the output to be formatted like this:

Desired Output Format:

Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4

Blah           Blah           Blah           Blah

---

```
            var query1 =
                from sD in newDataSet.SDTABLE.AsEnumerable()
                where sD.Field<int>("COL_Id") == 1
                let arr = new object[]
            {
                sD.Field<string>("COL_NAME")
            }
                select arr;

            foreach (var array in query1)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(array);  // prints values as individual rows
            }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853663/is-it-possible-to-switch-rows-and-columns-in-a-datagridview

Comment: Which answer did you choose?

Comment: svick answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853663/is-it-possible-to-switch-rows-and-columns-in-a-datagridview