# How to reverse rows in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a data grid, but the values do not display as I would like them to. My current code is below, how would I go about inverting the rows?

```
string[] strOutput = strLine.Split('_', ',','=');

int totalRows = Convert.ToInt16(strOutput[4]);
int totalCols = Convert.ToInt16(strOutput[5]);
int itemIndex = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++){ 
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col", "Col");
}
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(totalRows);
for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) { 
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = strOutput[itemIndex];
         itemIndex += 2;
    }                  
}
dataGridView1.Visible = true;
```

[image: Invert Rows]

Comment: If you mean you want to invert the srot order you should do just that: Change the sort order. If you don't have any you probably should. If you mean turn by 90° you can use [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853663/is-it-possible-to-switch-rows-and-columns-in-a-datagridview?rq=1) as a start..

Comment: how would I reverse the row sort order thoug? I don't need o transpose the rows and columns, I just need the rows inverted

Comment: If you actually __have__ a sort order you can revert is as usual. If it is a DBMS sort it is ORDER DESCENDING. If it is a Linq sort is is OderDescending(). If it is a BindingSource.Sort it is field DESC. But you never told us where the records come from..

Comment: the record comes from a text file, the string holds the rows, columns and values for grid. Example string---- 3,2,R1C1= 1, R1C2=4, R2C1=2,R2C2=5, R3C1=3,R3C2=6 but I need the row to be inverted.

Comment: So you added the Rows directly, without a DataSource? Then my answer should work.

Comment: Note the remarks at the end of my answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To invert i.e. reverse `DataGridViewRows` you can use this:

```
void ReverseDGVRows(DataGridView dgv)
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
    rows.AddRange(dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>());
    rows.Reverse();
    dgv.Rows.Clear();
    dgv.Rows.AddRange(rows.ToArray());
}
```

If you only need to do it once you could instead either:

- loop over the lines of the source file in reverse
- or instead of `Adding` the rows (to the end) `Insert` at the top:

---

```
dtnew.Rows.Insert(0, currentDataRowView.Row);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Inverting rows:

"DataGridView.Rows".- will give you "DataGridViewRowCollection"

Iterate the collection in reverse order and create a new datatable. (for loop from max size to zero)

Assign the new datatable to datagridview source.

**This rough code written in note pad  for your idea. I do not have IDE now.**

```
DataGridViewRowCollection dgRowColllection = dataGridView1.Rows;
DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
for(i = dataGridView1.RowCount; i  < 1 ; i--)
{
DataRowView currentDataRowView = dgRowColllection[i].Row;

dtnew.Rows.Add(currentDataRowView.Row);

}

dataGridView1.source = dtnew;
```

Comment: I do not have IDE now. I am adding the rough source code.

Comment: no.. these two lines modified/added                                         DataRowView currentDataRowView = dgRowColllection[i].Row;

dtnew.Rows.Add(currentDataRowView.Row);

Comment: DataRowView currentDataRowView = dgRowColllection[i].Row;  Row errors out for not having a definition

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on Pavan's answer because I don't have 50 reputation, but are you getting the error because the loop should be something like:

```
int totalRows = Convert.ToInt16(strOutput[4]);
int totalCols = Convert.ToInt16(strOutput[5]);
int itemIndex = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col", "Col");
}
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(totalRows);
for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < totalCols; j++)
       { 
           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = strOutput[itemIndex];
           itemIndex += 2;
       }
       DataGridViewRowCollection dgRowColllection = dataGridView1.Rows;
       DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
       for (i = dataGridView1.Items.Count; i < 1; i--)
       {
            DataRowView currentDataRowView = dgRowColllection[i].Row;
            dtnew.Rows.Add(currentDataRowView.Row);
       }
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dtnew;
   }    
   dataGridView1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: True boss. I have no IDE... I am on phone with app

Comment: Edited your code to include mine, has two errors, ---- for (i = dataGridView1.Items.Count; i < 1; i--)---- Items is looking for a definition and ----DataRowView currentDataRowView = dgRowColllection[i].Row;---- Row is looking for a definition